# Python Multiprocessing Not Killing all Subprocesses

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

So my first ever SO post!  here goes!

I am trying to implement Python Multiprocessing (Python 3.6) using a Queue.Manager Class, however I am finding that whilst functionally, my code works, it is not closing down the child processes.

```
def execute_parallel(self):
    """ Controlling function, function spawns worker processes and loads the task queue,
        monitors the complete_processes queue and terminates once process has finished
    """

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()

    # Define a list (queue) for tasks and complete_processes
    tasks = manager.Queue()
    complete_processes = manager.Queue()

    # Create process pool with the required number of processes
    num_processes = self.degree_of_parallel
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes)
    processes = []

    # Fill task queue with all of the required tasks from the calling module.
    queue_length = 0
    for single_task in self.task:
        tasks.put(single_task)
        queue_length += 1

    self.logger.info('Number of tasks in Queue : {}'.format(str(queue_length)))
    self.logger.info('INFO: Tasks in Queue : {}'.format(tasks.qsize()))

    # Quit the worker processes by sending them -1, append these to the end of the queue
    # One quit signal is required per number of Parallel Processes specified.
    for i in range(num_processes):
        tasks.put(-1)

    for i in range(num_processes):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.workers, args=('P{}'.format(i), tasks, complete_processes), daemon=True)
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

My Worker function is pretty simple, it pulls from the Queue until the queue is empty, for testing purposes, I have called a simple function that sleeps for 10 seconds.

```
def workers(self,process_name, tasks, complete_processes):
    """ Worker function, this executes the function, getting the task from the task list
        populating the result list on completion
        will break and kill the process, when -1 is present on the task list.
    """

    self.logger.info('{} Worker : Process Initiated'.format(process_name))

    try:
        while not tasks.empty():
            new_file = tasks.get()

            if new_file != -1:
                print('Parallel Process {} : PID is {}'.format(process_name, os.getpid()))
                self.logger.info('{} Worker : Started Processing {}'.format(process_name, os.path.basename(new_file[0])))
                self.sleep()
                complete_processes.put(new_file) # Load the Complete Processes Queue
                self.logger.info('{} Worker : Finished Processing {}'.format(process_name, os.path.basename(new_file[0])))
                print('Parallel Process {} : PID {} Finished'.format(process_name, os.getpid()))
            else:
                self.logger.info('{} Worker : Process Quits'.format(process_name))
                break
    except:
        self.logger.info('All Tasks Completed, Queue empty')

    return
```

However, when monitoring the PID's at the OS level, the number of processes continues to grow.

```
[root@632876de6086 /]# ps -ef | grep python3 | wc -l
11
[root@632876de6086 /]# ps -ef | grep python3 | wc -l
15
[root@632876de6086 /]# ps -ef | grep python3 | wc -l
19
[root@632876de6086 /]# ps -ef | grep python3 | wc -l
23
[root@632876de6086 /]# ps -ef | grep python3 | wc -l
26
[root@632876de6086 /]# ps -ef | grep python3 | wc -l
31
[root@632876de6086 /]# ps -ef | grep python3 | wc -l
35
```

In my test environment this isnt really an issue but in production, this is spawning thousands of child processes and ultimately is causing resource contention and problems with memory.

Any help, criticism or otherwise, greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just scanned through your code, but one thing caught my eye. Since you defined your processes pool, wouldn't you want to [`submit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) tasks to your `pool` rather then spawn `Process`es?

Comment: Hi @OndrejK., thanks for the response, do you believe this will resolve my issue or is this just another or a more efficient way of building a queue of tasks?

Comment: My problem seems to stem from the fact that I didn't build my queue manager within "main" , refactoring the code with this in mind has solved this issue

Comment: Cool. Sorry, I've just finished going through another post, but it seems like you're set now?